# How do I pass datagridview data to controls on new form?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

How do I pass data from a datagridview control on one form to controls on another form?  I'm using the following code to retrieve information from my database - then when the user selects the appropriate row, I want controls on another form to display the data corresponding to that row.  Is this possible and if so, how do I do it?

**Here's my code:**

```
If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("You must enter an account number to proceed!")
            TextBox1.Focus()
            Me.Refresh()
        Else
            Try
                dbConn = New MySqlConnection("Server=" & FormLogin.ComboBoxServerIP.SelectedItem & ";Port=3306;Uid=123456;Password=234567;Database=accounting")
                If dbConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                    dbConn.Close()
                End If
                dbConn.Open()
                Dim dbAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT ccNumber, ccExpireMonth, ccExpireYear, ccZipcode FROM cc_master WHERE customer_accountNumber = " & TextBox1.Text, dbConn)
                Dim myDatatable As New DataTable
                dbAdapter.Fill(myDatatable)
                If myDatatable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    DataGridView1.DataSource = myDatatable
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("No Customer Records Found!  Please try again!")
                    TextBox1.Clear()
                    TextBox1.Focus()
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("A DATABASE ERROR HAS OCCURED" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message & vbCrLf & _
                            vbCrLf + "Please report this to the IT/Systems Helpdesk at Ext 131.")
            End Try

        End If
```

Comment: Provide public properties in that from which get/set the controls' values. Then you just need a reference to that form in the other.

Comment: Could you help me out with an example of how you would do this with my code?  Assume this form is Form1 and the target form is Form2.

Answer (score 0):

Better is to make Static Class and put the data of the selected row in it and then access the data from that class to another form.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I don't know how to do this yet.